# Loop won't display if union is declared

Tags: c, for-loop, unions

Why does the `for` loop in the code below not seem to run if I include the declaration of the `union test`? I'm using the clang compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

union test{
    int intv;
    float floatv;
};

int main(){
    union test test1; // When this is removed the below loop displays.

    for(int i, j = 0; i < 5; i++, j = (j + i) * 2){
        printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i` isn't initialized

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a typo. cleblanc and yano are right. Its undefined behaviour. I didn't realise both variables wouldn't be initialised with the zero like they are in some other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's undefined behavior. You never initialized `i`.